# How to attack solving for similarity transformed quantities

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I'm interested in solving equations of the form:
$$
R\mathbf{x}R^{T}=\alpha\mathbf{x}+k
$$
where $R$ is a orthonormal matrix (rotation), $\alpha$ is a scalar multiplier (non-zero), $k\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is some constant, and $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is what I'm actually looking for. I've toyed with the idea of multiplying everything out by hand and then working backwards, but I'm hopeful that there is maybe a more straight forward / elegant solution.

For what it's worth, my ultimate objective is to try to formulate a recursive least-squares estimation problem. My thought was that I could do the following:

1) Solve my original optimization problem in closed form
2) Take derivatives of the solution w/r/t all the input variables -- this gives me the dynamics of the system in a control-theory sense
3) Given 1 and 2, I now have a system whose state is the currently optimal solution given the data and whose dynamics describe how the optimal state changes as new data is added.

Once I get to #3, I can apply tools like from the Kalman Filter or Particle Filter families to get the answer I'm looking for. Assuming, of course, that I am even on a viable path in the first place.

Edit: tried to clarify that $k$ is a constant vector.

Comment: When you say $k$ is a constant, do you mean that $k$ is some constant vector in $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: Also, if $R$ is a square matrix, then the products $Rx$ and $xR^T$ cannot both be valid.

Comment: Good point @Omnomnomnom :-/ I think I likely messed up a derivative somewhere.